# discord bot c# read received direct message

Tags: c#, bots, discord, discord.net

I'm currently trying to create my own bot for my Discord server. I'd like for a user to be able to type the command **event then the bot will direct message that user and ask it some questions for the event, such as title, time, etc.

I'm able to get the bot to direct message the user but I can't find how to get the bot to read the message the user sends back.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Event : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext> {

    private static IUser currentUser;
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;

    [Command("event")]
    public async Task EventAsync() {
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();

        var id = Context.User.Mention;

        if(currentUser == null) {
            foreach(var user in Context.Guild.Users) {
                if(("<@!" + user.Id.ToString() + ">") == id) {
                    currentUser = user;
                    id = user.Mention;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        await currentUser.SendMessageAsync("Enter event title:");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. In the main program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    => new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

public async Task RunBotAsync() {
    _client.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
}

private async Task MessageReceived(SocketMessage msg) {
    //Code to direct message here
}
```